# Cloudable (java) app in OpenStack

Tags: cloud, openstack

I'm working in a market where the customers are asking questions and are curious about cloud computing and virtualization. I've done some initial google/wikipedia reading on OpenStack to try and get a grip on how (java-) applications would be designed for and run in a cloud.

Anyone care to give me some hints on how to get some hands-on experience? I'm building a system with a core service that will support for a big number of concurrent clients, requesting transnational work towards a database (and eachother). To that I will add support/OAMP-interfaces, probably both WS and web UI.

/Clueless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general OpenStack doesn't care what you're running on the VM's, let it be java. What you need to research is how to make your app [scalable horizontally](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/best-practices-for-horizontal-application-scaling), to be able to increase workload limit just by introducing the new nodes.

A few other links that may help:

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/NetworkLoadBalancingIntegrationsWithQuantum - Load balancing in OpenStack

https://www.openshift.com/ - Autoscalable PaaS built over OpenStack

Comment: so you're saying that if my app today can scale, with the help of an LB, putting it in an (openstack) cloud is merely a setup issue?

Comment: If we're talking about pure OpenStack - Yes. It provides you with clear VMs using the image you provided, gives you all the infrastructure, so you need just make sure your app properly deployed on the VM. If you want to use something like OpenShift - you'll need to research what the requirements are, and what platform components OpenShift can provide you with..

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'm going to move forward with my current design then and make sure my product scales, then get professional help with packaging/VM/OpenStacks to get virtualization and OpenStack going.